# issue with ie10 not showing certain content

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-10, doctype

I have an `iframe` that calls a PHP file to dispay some text links.  The `iframe` shows fine if i change document mode to ie9 in ie10. But in ie10 standard (or quirks) mode the content will not appear. Below is the link to the `iframe` source I am trying to show

http://www.businessdictionary.com/ad_server/iframe.php?id=34

I have tried all the options listed below:

1) Add doctype

2) Used all the combination of X-UA-Compatible meta tag

But nothing is helping.

Not sure if its the issue with IE10 or something in the page.

Comment: the page linked above works without issue in Chrome and Firefox. The issue is only with ie

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. This page uses tons of document.write calls instead of manipulating DOM objects.

If you change the injected JavaScript from this:
`document.write ('<a href="http://oascentral.businessdictionary.com/RealMedia/ads/click_lx.ads/w...'`

to this:
`document.write ('.<a href="http://oascentral.businessdictionary.com/RealMedia/ads/click_lx.ads/w...`

then the page works just fine.

Comment: i tried to change and did not work for me. The issue is only with ie10 standard mode.

Comment: Works fine in IE10 Standards for me. Got a repro URL for your updated version?